# How can I get UIGestureRecognizer to work with manually added subviews

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer

I programmatically made a subview and it shows up in my main view.   It also has a separate view controller.
Though my gestureRecognizers work on UIImageViews in the main view, they do not work in my sub view.

Here's what I have in the main view controller:

```swift
var hVC: HandViewController = HandViewController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createHandImageView()
}

func createHandImageView() {
    addChildViewController(hVC)
    let w: CGFloat = cardWidth + ((hVC.maxHandCards-1) * hVC.handCardSep)
    let h: CGFloat = cardHeight
    let screenWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let screenHeight = view.frame.size.height
    let x: CGFloat = (screenWidth - w) / 2
    let frame = CGRectMake(x, screenHeight - cardHeight - 20, w, h)
    hVC.view = UIImageView(frame: frame)
    hVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    // This is where I add the Hand View that eventually holds the card views
    view.addSubview(hVC.view)
    hVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}
```

And the sub view controller:

```swift
init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() // This NEVER fires
    NSLog("did load");
}

func updateHandCardsView(cards: [Int]) {
    handCardViews = [];
    for card in cards {
        addNewHandCardImage(card)
    }
}

func addNewHandCardImage(card: Int) {
    let imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cardWidth, cardHeight));
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: Deck.getCardName(card))
    // This is where I add each Card View to the Hand View
    self.view.addSubview(imageView)
    handCardViews.append(imageView)
    addEventRecognizers(imageView)
}

func addEventRecognizers(view: UIImageView) {
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "highlightCard:")
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "playCard:")
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
}
```

All the card views show up in the hand view.  All programmatically created.
When I copy and paste the gesture code into the main view and use it on the cards on the table, the action gets called, but not in the sub view (HandView).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gesture recognizers only work on views that they belong to. There is a UIView method to add gesture recognizers. Your addEventRecognizers is only adding recognizers to whatever UIImageView passed in. You should change the function call to accept UIView, since UIImageView is just a subclass of UIView, it will still work on your images. Then call

```
addEventRecognizers(HandView) //Pass in the view that will get set with gesture recognizer.
```

Alternatively, if you just want to add one gesture recognizer just call `HandView.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)`

Comment: I was confused with your reply but I tried it.  And it CLICKED!!!  However, I simply passed in view (which is what I guess you meant by HandView as I'm already in the HandViewController).  It worked because any where I clicked in the HandView container registered, but the clicks weren't at all connected to the cards images views.

I am excited that I can at least get a manually created subview to recognize tap events.  So how do I get the card image views themselves to do the same?

Comment: Let me clarify a bit as you answer was based on limited info.  I have a ViewController that controls the main window.  Then I added my HandViewController.view as a subView.  In turn, within HandViewController, I did self.view.addSubview(imageView) where imageView represents a card image view for each card in the hand.  So the card view is in the hand view is in the main view.  Adding the recognizer to the handview works but is useless because the recognizer needs to work on the cards.

Comment: I added both the HandViewController.view and all the CardImageViews to the gestureRecognizer and it worked.  I don't understand why but - thank you so much.

Comment: Your actually adding gesture recognizers to the views not the other way around. Like in your code above in `addEventRecognizers:` you added multiple different gestures to one view. Its a views instance that calls the `addGestureRecognizer:` method. Just to help you grasp the concept of GestureRecognizer. Sorry I couldn't respond to your first comments in a timely manner.

Comment: Matt - I still don't understand.  I added the gestures to each of all the Card views.  It didn't work.  But when I added it also to the superview (HandView) , it worked.  Why?